# How to send data from SQLite database to Firebase database

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a Android app that stores data like name, number to SQLite database. I need to push the data from SQLite to Firebase.

This is the SQLite code for the app which stores the data in `detailsdb`

```
sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "DetailsDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DETAILS(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, location VARCHAR)");
onClick save

            try {
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                        eName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        ePhonenumber.getText().toString().trim(),
                        eLocation.getText().toString().trim()
                );

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                eName.setText("");
                ePhonenumber.setText("");
                eLocation.setText("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I need to sync or insert into Firebase database from `detailsdb.sqlite` here

```
 if(isOnline(MainActivity.this))

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet is Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Read SQlite db and sync/Store them to firebase.


    }
```

Comment: use this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I have seen it..it is showing about reading and writing to firebase database but my question is to read the data from sqlite db and send to firebase

Comment: so ur asking the steps to read data from the table and send to firebase ?

Comment: i know how to save data in SQLite and how to save data in firebase database.But the thing i want to do is push the sqlite data to firebase when device is online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create A class Like Below:

```
class Details{
   public String eName,ePhonenumber,eLocation;
   public Details(String name,String number,String location){
        this.eName = name;
        this.ePhonenumber = number;
        this.eLocation = location;
   }
}
```

use the query like this to fetch data from sqlite:

```
List<Details> dataList = new ArrayList<Details>;
Cursor c = sqLiteHelper.rawQuery("select * from DETAILS",null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        dataList.add(new Details(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"))))
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

and you can send to firebase like this

```
if(dataList.size() > 0 ){
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DETAILS");
    for(Details d : dataList){
        ref.push().setValue(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: List<Details> dataList = new ArrayList<Details>(); and is that sqliteHelper.rawQuery() is like getData from SQLite Helper ??

Comment: List<Details> dataList = new ArrayList<Details>() is to initalize a empty list and add data from the sqliteHelper.rawQuery() in to the list

Comment: what i need to return in the rawquery from SQLite helper.class as it needed to create a public class ..
 public Cursor rawQuery(String s,Object o) {

        return ;

    }

Comment: SQLite helper.class returns a cursor object which contains all the data inside it. that we are accessing it using the cursor iterator and looping through it and adding the items into the list

Comment: bro can we check the phonenumber from bothe sqlite and firebase Details  and then can we perform the data posting to firebase because everytime i open the app the data redundancy is happening in the firebase db