# Uploading a local database to Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I want to upload my local SQLite Database to Firebase. I have created SQLite database which is stored in data/databases. Is there any way I can upload and download this database with the help of Firebase? Any help will be appreciated. And I want to use Firebase Storage not Realtime Database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send data from SQLite database to Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198959/how-to-send-data-from-sqlite-database-to-firebase-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a local file, you can upload it to Firebase Storage using its API. An example of that can be found in the Firebase documentation on [uploading a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file):

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);
```

Check the link for full documentation.